# How to calculate running time from status and time using python

Tags: python

I have a circulation pump that I check wither it's on or off on and this is not by any fixed interval what so ever. For a single day that could give me a dataset looking like this where 'value' represents the pump being on or off.

```
data=(
 {'value': 0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 7, 58, 25)},
 {'value': 1, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 8, 0, 3)},
 {'value': 0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 8, 32, 10)},
 {'value': 0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 9, 22, 7)},
 {'value': 1, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 9, 30, 58)},
 {'value': 1, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 12, 2, 23)},
 {'value': 0, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 15, 43, 11)},
 {'value': 1, 'time': datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 18, 20, 14, 55)})
```

The format is not that important and can be changed.

What I do want to know is how to calculate how many minutes ( or timespan or whatever) the `'value'` has been 0 or 1 (or ON or OFF)?

This is just a small sample of the data, it stretches over several years so there could be a lot.
I have been using numpy/mathplotlib for plotting some graphs and there might be something in numpy to do this but I'm not good enough at it.

**Edit**

What I would like to see as an output to this would be a sum of the time in the different states. Something like...

```
0 04:42:13  
1 07:34:17
```

Comment: It was off on 2011-01-18 07:58:25 and on on 2011-01-18 08:00:03. But what was its state between these two instants?

Comment: the value is always what the entry says until it changes. So for these two it was 0 until 8:00:03 after that it was 1 until 8:32:10 and then off again....

Comment: are this actual sums? or is it just an example?

Comment: just example... just did the actual...

    0=05:32:10

    1=06:44:20

Comment: The last entry with 1 as value can not be calculated and I could simply drop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you're going to treat this data points, are they representative of what? Generally, to know when switch occur  you could use `itertools.groupby` like this:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> for i, grp in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x['value']):
    lst = [x['time'] for x in grp]
    print(i, max(lst) - min(lst))


0 0:00:00
1 0:00:00
0 0:49:57
1 2:31:25
0 0:00:00
1 0:00:00
```

This is the example of minimal time you can be sure your system was up or down (assuming no interruptions between measurement).

Once you decide how to treat your points, modification to this algorithm would be trivial.

---

**EDIT**: since you only need sums of up/down-time, here is the simpler version:

```
>>> sums = {0:datetime.timedelta(0), 1:datetime.timedelta(0)}
>>> for cur, nex in zip(data, data[1:]):
    sums[cur['value']] += nex['time'] - cur['time']


>>> for i, j in sums.items():
    print(i, j)


0 5:32:10
1 6:44:20
```

If you expect long-periods of continuous up/down-time, you might still benefit of the `itertools.groupby`. This is py3k version, so it won't be particularly efficient in py2k.

Comment: Your example would give me the time since the previous change.

Comment: @birchroad: I think output demonstrates quite clearly that that is not the case. Having read your comment, it seems, my example could be changed to accommodate your requirement. Do you have problems with this trivial change?

Comment: I like what I see. Unfortunately I'm stuck with py2k but I'll run some test and see if it is "quick enough"

Comment: @birchroad: if you're stuck with py2k, use `itertools.izip` and `sums.iteritems`, instead of `zip` and `sums.items`, these are tiny optimizations (especially, `items` one). The `groupby` optimization that I mentioned in answer could be beneficial on both version of python. Whether it is, would depend on the actual data.